# Error of combo box for my windows form application

Tags: winforms, wcf, user-interface

I am currently developing a WCF publish subscribe service for my asp.net publisher and the windows form application subscriber.

For the windows form application, I would be using a flow layout panel to generate the list of panels (of notifications) for my application. When the publisher(asp.net application) publish a post to the service, every subscriber would be able to receive the information and update their panels accordingly.  As for my flowlayoutpanel, I have a ComboBox to filter the types of notification, mainly type 1 and 2.

the code for the ComboBox alert is

```
private void comboAlertType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  flowLayoutForAlert.Dispose();

  populateList();
  if (comboAlertType.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
    flowLayoutForAlert = createFlowLayoutPanel(1);
  }
  else if (comboAlertType.SelectedIndex == 1)
  {
    flowLayoutForAlert = createFlowLayoutPanel(2);
  }
  else
  {
    flowLayoutForAlert = createFlowLayoutPanel(3);
  }
  this.Controls.Add(flowLayoutForAlert);
}
```

the createFlowlayoutpanel(#) is just a method for me to create the panels.  The integer inside stands for the type of panels shown, mainly 1 for every single panels, 2 for important ones and 3 for normal ones.

for my PostReceived() callback method for the wcf service, i have the following code

```
public void PostReceived(String alertId)
{
  backgroundForm b = (backgroundForm) Application.OpenForms[0];

  b.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
  {
      b.getMainFormObject().lblSearch.Text = "lakjslkaja";
      b.getSettingsFormObject().player.Play();
      b.getMainFormObject().notificationList.Add(new notificationForm("", "", "", "", "", "", 1, 1));
      b.getMainFormObject().populateList();
      b.getMainFormObject().mainFormLoad();
  });
}
```

the code for the mainFormLoad is

```
public void mainFormTesting()
{
  notificationForm tempForm = (notificationForm)notificationList[0];
  tempForm.Show();

  flowLayoutForAlert = createFlowLayoutPanel(1);
  this.Controls.Add(flowLayoutForAlert);
}
```

when I first start the application, the combobox alert filter works for the initial amount of panels, but when I publisher a post and the app receives the post, it sort of screws up the combo box filter function.

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: "it sort of screws up the combo box filter function" - can you be more specific?  Screws it up how?  What do you see?  How is what you see different from what you expect/want?

Comment: as normally I click the different choices in the combo box, I would get the different filter views for my program. but after I posted once, it doesnt really filter the choices anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by first disposing the original panels before calling the codes above.